# Template Size Recursion -- Constructor Multiple Overloads

Tags: c++, templates, recursion

I'm doing an exercise (not homework; it's self-assigned) that requires a templated class that calls a class half as large with a function.  Naturally this means recursion continues until some base case (n == 1).  The problem I'm running into is that I also want to write a constructor based on F, which is leading to "Multiple Overloads" when n == 0 (with the copy-constructor, as 0/2 == 0).

```
template<size_t n>
struct Foo {
    Foo() {};
    Foo(const Foo<n / 2>& x) {};
    Foo<n / 2> bar() {
        Foo<n / 2> rtn;
        if(n > 1) {
            rtn.bar();
        }
        rtn.bar();
        return rtn;
    }
}

int main(int, char const**) {
    Foo<4> a;
    Foo<2> b = a.bar();
}
```

Is there anyway around this?  Specializing either constructor for n == 0 doesn't work because I'm still left with two constructors.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can disambiguate the 'recurring constructor' by adding an unused parameter

```
Foo(const Foo<n / 2>& x, int) {};
```

In this way the case n=0,1 is still different from copy constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The best work-around I've found is to specialize the entire struct/class

```
template<size_t n>
struct Foo {
    Foo() {};
    Foo(const Foo& x) {};
    Foo(const Foo<n / 2>& x) {}
    Foo<n / 2> bar() const {
        Foo<n / 2> rtn;
        if(n > 1) {
            rtn.bar();
        }
        return rtn;
    };
    double data[n];
};

template <>
struct Foo<0> {
    Foo() {};
    Foo(const Foo& x) {};
    Foo bar() const {
        Foo rtn;
        return rtn;
    };
    double* data;
};
```

Comment: No need to speciaiize the entire class. With explicit specialization you can do `template<>Foo<0>::bar()const{return{};}`